# How do I Append a string to a list using dynamodb sdk? (Java)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Pretty simple problem, but for some reason there is no correct documentation anywhere. Here is what I am implementing:

```
public static AttributeValue pushMessage(String ID,String message)
{
    Map<String, AttributeValue> itemKey = mapKey(KEY, new AttributeValue(ID));

    UpdateItemRequest request = new UpdateItemRequest();
    request.setTableName(TABLE_NAME);
    request.setKey(itemKey);
    /*I don't know what to put for the update expression*/
    //request.setUpdateExpression("ADD #"+LIST_NAME+" :append_value)");
    request.setUpdateExpression("list_append("+LIST_NAME+", :append_value)");
    request.setExpressionAttributeValues(Collections.singletonMap(":append_value", new AttributeValue(message)));

    UpdateItemResult result = dynamoDB.updateItem(request);
}
```

I essentially just want to be able to append strings to a list I have in the items in my DB. I have tried everything the documentations have suggested(so basically 1 example) and numerous  threads, but nothing works.

The error I am currently getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "list_append", near: "list_append(" (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:919)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:449)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:411)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:360)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2048)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2018)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1845)
at DBConnector.pushMessage(DBConnector.java:486)
at DBConnector.main(DBConnector.java:506)
```

Comment: what is the value of `LIST_NAME` at the time you run the code, how do you define it ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri LIST_NAME is a String object that holds the key of the list i am trying to append to.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri So say schema looks like: {"ID":"4321","Queue":["String1","String2"]} LIST_NAME would be "Queue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following UpdateExpression:

```
String.format("SET %s = list_append(%s, :append_value)", LIST_NAME, LIST_NAME)
```